# The history of Electronic Knowledge

Tags: history

I am an Electronic Instructor. In each basic course I have to teach one chapter as " The History of Electronic Engineering " which does not take long. Nevertheless I have to give a short and clear-cut concept to the students. At the moment I have tried some , but not sure about the reality. Is there any topic in this site by which I can check my data ?

Comment: Ask at your local library. I'm sure they'll be happy to point you to the relevant literature.

Comment: Look at Wikipedia, including sources mentioned in Wikipedia. Use Google to find sites specifically devoted to the history of electricity and electronics. This site is not about that and is not about directing people to other specific sites or references. Note that many sites say that Thales wrote about static electricity by rubbing amber. Detailed information about Thales indicates that no writings by Thales are known to exist and no direct quotations of writings by Thales are known to exist. However Aristotle apparently attributed that knowledge to Thales. Search Ben Franklin re lightning.

Comment: For ancient history, you have the unconfirmed Baghdad battery, then skip ahead to 1600 and outward, with the invention of the word electricus. Static electricity, Leyden jars, invention of the battery, laplace transform, EM fields , electrolysis, first motors around 1830ish. All this is standard encyclopedic knowledge.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the page for other parts of this site. There is a history section under culture / recreation and a history of science section under science. Click more at the bottom of the category to see all of the topics in the category.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what slant you want your research to be; the history of failures or success in truth or wisdom of nature , or the commercial consequences or the growth of relevant laws of physics or the number of inventions resulting from this.

I find no better book to read than *"A  Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism"* by **James Clerk Maxwell** M.A.  1873  He read all the research by Michael Faraday *before* reading any of the Math by; Laplace, Poisson, Green and Gauss, then Weber, Neumann, Lorenz, Heaviside and  Hamilton. With examples by; Nicholson, Volta, Varley, Thomson, Coulomb, Holtz, Hertz, Ohm, Paalzow, Kohlrausch, Nippoldt. Wiedemann and Riihlinann.

He starts with a foundation of basic measurement and math, two essential "languages" whose researchers were often isolated from each other in ability to understand the other.  He describes the research from 1 to 3 dimensions, magnetism, atomic, mechanical, and current in conductors and dielectrics.

He mentions some history from the use of amber, loadstone and the relation to heat, light and chemical reactions.  Maxwell credits most of this treatise to the wisdom of Sir William **Thomson** who convinced him that the contradictions between the experiments of Michael Faraday and German Mathematicians were not wrong, but both necessary.

For any student I suggest, learning in the same order;  understand phenomena, then theory, and repeat to the next higher level of complexity until you can see how they connected in an exquisite simple harmony.